# How to do WC meta_query on variable products via their product variations?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata

On WooCommerce products, I have a custom meta field called "amazon_price" and I wanna hide the products from showing on front-end if no price is set for this "amazon_price" custom field.

I used this code to do the filtering which works fine for simple products but it doesn't show variable products even if they have "amazon_price" field set , My guess the reason behind that issue is that this code maybe looking for "amazon_price" field value on the main post ID for the product so I think this could might be looking for the main post id for the variable product instead of looking for that field into the variable id, but even if my guess was true I still dont know how to fix that.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'apm_products_meta_query' );
function apm_products_meta_query( $q ){
    $meta_query = $q->get( 'meta_query' );

    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'       => 'amazon_price',
        'value'     => 0,
        'compare'   => '>'
    );

    $q->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
}
```

Comment: I really apologize aboout that, a few hours past with now answer so i though that if my question went after page 1 or 2 i will have no change to get an answer at all that's why i dublicated it.. btw i deleted the dublicated questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that is possible to make a WC meta query for product variations of variable products. But a with a custom light SQL query you can make everything at the same time:

```
// The custom SQL query
function custom_query_incl_ids() {
    global $wpdb;

    $meta_key = 'amazon_price';

    return $wpdb->get_col( "
        SELECT DISTINCT p.ID FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts p
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        WHERE p.post_type = 'product' AND p.post_status = 'publish'
        AND ( ( pm.meta_key = '$meta_key' AND pm.meta_value > 0 )
        OR p.ID IN (
            SELECT DISTINCT v.post_parent FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts v
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as vm ON v.ID = vm.post_id
            WHERE v.post_type = 'product_variation'
            AND v.post_status = 'publish' AND v.post_parent > 0
            AND vm.meta_key = '$meta_key' AND vm.meta_value > 0
        ) )
    ");
}

// The WC query
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'product_query_action_callback' );
function product_query_action_callback( $q ){
    $q->set( 'post__in', (array) custom_query_incl_ids() );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer which seems to be working perfectly for default product loop however i always use a filter plugin that has a builtin query filter. This is the function i was using with that plugin which worked nicely but had the main issue with variable products

```
add_filter('prdctfltr_meta_query', 'prdctfltr_apm_query');
function prdctfltr_apm_query($meta_query) {
      $meta_query[] = array(
                  'key'       => 'amazon_price',
                  'value'     => 0,
                  'compare'   => '>'
              );
return $meta_query;
}
```

Comment: So im wondering how to implement your query with this filter givin that syntax?
I tried ``` $meta_query = product_query_action_callback();``` but it didn't work

Comment: @IslamMohamed When using `post__in` it seems that it disable the **meta query** *(and the **tax query** too)*. So you need to include your query in the SQL…

Comment: I think since i have to use that filter this plugin provide 'prdctfltr_meta_query' to do the query and since this wp filter expect a WC meta query as input so i though of an idea to alter the custom field save function so the custom field value (for the variation that has the highest value) saved not only in the the variation id but on the parent post id too, what do you think of this idea?

Comment: @IslamMohamed Yes that is a smart idea